# Sliders not showing up: setREVStartSize is not defined

Tags: php, wordpress, revolution-slider

After I upgrade my Revolution slider plugin (5.4.5.1) for Wordpress (4.8) I start to get this error: setREVStartSize is not defined

I'm trying differents approaches to fix this but without success. Is this a specific js file to be loaded in order to fix this? I don't if my theme is loading all assets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This happened to me after updating to the latest version 6.0.6.

I was able to fix it by clicking "Globals" link in the top of the Slider Revolution main dashboard page, and then selecting "Include Libraries Globally".

Comment: I am having the same issue, can you please share the screenshot of setting area. I have enabled this option and saved changes, but unfortunately, it's not  resolved my issue.

Comment: @ArchanaSharma Do not forget `Purge All` - the answer fixed it!

Comment: This (turning on Include libraries globally) fixed it. However, if you don't want to include the libraries globally, just add the page IDs in the field under that option. That works as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible cause is your setting in RevSlider Global settings. Turning off 'Include RevSlider libraries globally' and then trying to include a slider on a page that is not explicitly defined by ID in the field 'Pages to include RevSlider libraries' will trigger this error. The latter field does not take page slugs, so it should be a comma separated list of IDs and/or `homepage`.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, spent two weeks on this and have not figured it out....

This "setREVstartsize" is a newly added API function?

Please review; http://www.madcoilbuilt.com

Im losing my mind, if someone is able to offer any insight that would be amazing! I had slider working previously and I migrated the WP installation to another host and ever since then, garbage....

Comment: The provided link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the `revslider shortcode` is placed before the `wp_head();` function call. Make sure that all the base scripts are loaded properly first.

Comment: I know that, but before upgrade the plugin it was working fine. To keep the web site working I restored the previous version and is working. I'll create a new test environment to work on this newer version. Thanks!

Comment: this might sound silly, but worth checking - is the plugin activated after the upgrade

Comment: Yes, the plugin was activated. Tonight I'll get a fresh Wordpress environment to test this new version. I don't have an usual installation of Wordpress, my website was developed using Laravel and few routes is managed by Wordpress, the revSlider and others plugins were working fine before this upgrade. I'll post my tests results later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a JavaScript code that I had inserted in the header without close properly the script tag. I had not updated neither wordpress, nor plugins, nor themes.
I had just installed "Insert Headers and Footers" plugin and put the **code with issues** there

Answer (score 0):

Solved in LiteSpeed Cache

Navigate to:
`Page Optimisation` > `Js Setting` [Tab]

Under `Load Inline JS` (last option) select `Deferred`

[Save Changes]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with this error.

For me removing the line below from my script enque file fixed it:

//remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);