# Error after updating Slider Revolution to latest version 6.0.6 :: ReferenceError: setREVStartSize is not defined

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have updated "Slider Revolution" WordPress plugin version to 6.0.6 and now it gives me an error:

> ReferenceError: setREVStartSize is not defined

I have tried solutions mentioned in previously asked questions, but it doesn't work for me.

**Environment**::

1. WordPress:: 5.2.2
2. Slider Revolution::6.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same problem. I did find this fix - select "Globals" in Rev Slider settings and add the page ID or select Include Libraries Globally. However, this fix just seems to work for logged in users.
[Sliders not showing up: setREVStartSize is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066543/sliders-not-showing-up-setrevstartsize-is-not-defined)

Comment: I have also tried this method before, but unfortunately, this is working on the local environment and have an issue on live site. I have tried after clearing cache still this exists.

Comment: I just updated to version 6.0.7 and it appears to be functioning normally. The update should fix it!


Version notes:
Version 6.0.7 (23th July 2019) Changes: Changed global option "Include libraries globally" default value to on, please set it to off manually again if wanted. Changed the second parameter of the function temporary_remove_sizes() to be optional. Added filter revslider_include_libraries again. Bugfixes: Fixed a bug where a custom navigation could lead to the slide editor not beeing able to be loaded for that slider

Answer (score 0):

the `setREVStartSize` function is inline javascript.
make sure you are not minifying and deferring your inline JavaScript using some kind of cache plugin. that was the problem for me.